# NSDate from NSString adjusted to device timzone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an `NSString` like this :

```
 NSString *playTime = @"20:45";// GMT
```

I need to convert this string to `NSDate` (only hours and seconds) then adjusted to device timezone.

Example:

If user device timezone is set to **GMT**, I need a result like this : **@"20:45"**;

If user device timezone is set to **GMT + 2**, I need a result like this : **@"22:45"**;

Comment: You could look here for further information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Why would you need `NSDate` to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *gmtDateString = @"20:45";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

//Now you have date in GMT time zone by default dateFormatter timezone would be in local time zone
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//set to local time zone
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

//Now you have string in localDate format
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for date conversion as per your requirement.

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    logDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"20:45"];
     NSLog(@"Date %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:logDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will calculate the time w.r.t. local time zone.
Suppose my time zone is **`GMT+05:30`** so the time **`05:30`** will become **`00:00`**.

```
NSString *playTime = @"20:45";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:playTime];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

**Log is:** `2000-01-01 15:15:00 +0000`